# debian: Network interfaces RAISE issue on dual ethernet card 82576-CE-2T-X1

Tags: networking, debian, ethernet

Hello fellow superusers,

I run into a problem when setting up my dual ethernet card 82576-GE-2T-X1. I successfully make the latest driver igb and installed the module after removing the previous igb module. So, everything is fine until network raise of my /etc/network/interfaces - the raise failed.

Here is my interfaces file:

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto enp3s0
allow-hotplug enp3s0
iface enp3s0 inet dhcp 

auto enp1s0f0
iface enp1s0f0 inet static
address 10.0.0.12/24
gateway 10.0.0.12

auto enp1s0f1
iface enp1s0f1 inet static
address 192.168.0.12/24
gateway 192.168.0.10
```

Here is the "systemctl status networking.service" message:

```
● networking.service - Raise network interfaces
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/networking.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2019-11-24 12:48:55 CET; 45s ago
     Docs: man:interfaces(5)
  Process: 1922 ExecStart=/sbin/ifup -a --read-environment (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 1922 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
```

here is the "journalctl -xe" message:

```
 Defined-By: systemd
 Support: https://www.debian.org/support
 
 An ExecStart= process belonging to unit networking.service has exited.
 
 The process' exit code is 'exited' and its exit status is 1.
Nov 24 12:51:37 rond systemd[1]: networking.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
 Subject: Unit failed
 Defined-By: systemd
 Support: https://www.debian.org/support
 
 The unit networking.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'exit-code'.
Nov 24 12:51:37 rond systemd[1]: Failed to start Raise network interfaces.
 Subject: A start job for unit networking.service has failed
 Defined-By: systemd
 Support: https://www.debian.org/support
 
 A start job for unit networking.service has finished with a failure.
 
 The job identifier is 1034 and the job result is failed.
```

> $ sudo ifup enp1s0f1
>
> RTNETLINK answers: File exists
>
> ifup: failed to bring up enp1s0f1

So, the two new interfaces can't raise (out of a total of 3, including the motherboard nic), can't ping of course.

Does anyone has some clues? (I try to contact also the card vendor ipolex)

Thank you for your insights :-)

/cr!ptal

Comment: systemd likes to kill the most important log data. What does an `ifup enp1s0f0/1` say? Please extend it into your question.

Comment: thank you https://superuser.com/users/208950/peterh-says-reinstate-monica, I added it

Answer (score 0):

ok, I figured it out:

I replaced /etc/network/interfaces from initial post with:

> '# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
>
> '# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).
>
> source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*
>
> '# The loopback network interface
>
> auto lo
>
> iface lo inet loopback
>
> auto enp3s0
>
> allow-hotplug enp3s0
>
> iface enp3s0 inet dhcp
>
> allow-hotplug enp1s0f0
>
> iface enp1s0f0 inet static
>
> address 10.0.0.12
>
> netmask 255.255.255.0
>
> gateway 10.0.0.12
>
> allow-hotplug enp1s0f1
>
> iface enp1s0f1 inet static
>
> address 192.168.0.12
>
> netmask 255.255.255.0
>
> gateway 192.168.0.10

and now it works like a charm. Cant' wait to test the through output of this new card :-)

have a nice day,

/cr!ptal